# Math calculation breaks in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I have a long equation written in coffeescript, which turns in a function call when compiled to JavaScript:

**CoffeeScript:**

```
@u[idx] = @max(0, currU + t * ((@dU * ((@uu[right] + @uu[left] + @uu[bottom] + @uu[top]) -4 * currU) - d2) + currF * (1.0 - currU)))
```

**JavaScript:**

```
this.max(0, currU + t * ((this.dU * ((this.uu[right] + this.uu[left] + this.uu[bottom] + this.uu[top])(-4 * currU)) - d2) + currF * (1.0 - currU)));
```

The problem is this part:

```
((@uu[right] + @uu[left] + @uu[bottom] + @uu[top]) -4 * currU)
```

which turns into a function call:

```
((this.uu[right] + this.uu[left] + this.uu[bottom] + this.uu[top])(-4 * currU))
```

Can someone explain whats going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
@u[idx] = @max(0, currU + t * ((@dU * ((@uu[right] + @uu[left] + @uu[bottom] + @uu[top]) - 4 * currU) - d2) + currF * (1.0 - currU)))
```

Which compiles to:

```
this.u[idx] = this.max(0, currU + t * ((this.dU * ((this.uu[right] + this.uu[left] + this.uu[bottom] + this.uu[top]) - 4 * currU) - d2) + currF * (1.0 - currU)));
```

The silly little issue is the `-4`, vs `- 4`.

Without the space, the compiler assumes the `-4 * currU` to be an argument to the *'function'* , `(@uu[right] + @uu[left] + @uu[bottom] + @uu[top])`.

Comment: There is ambiguity in `expr1 -expr2`. Does it mean `expr1 - expr2` or `expr1(-expr2)`? If you unpack `expr2` the intent is obvious but the parser isn't as smart as it pretends to be and makes the "wrong" choice.